# what does "U.S.-centric prints" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody tell me what *U.S.-centric prints* means in this Bloomberg article?

> Policy makers should be prepared to consider raising rates next month despite recent volatility, Kansas City Fed President Esther George said on Tuesday, citing her outlook for solid growth this year.
>
> “Although global economic conditions still remain relatively austere, U.S.-centric prints remain hopeful, especially on the labor front, while inflation is likely to tick higher in second half as transitory effects from low oil and import prices dissipate,” Gan said.

("[Top Forecaster Says ‘Gold the Superhero’ May Rally to $1,400](http://washpost.bloomberg.com/Story?docId=1376-O311LL6K50YC01-318DF3CS9G3EI7PJ9NMO7P7QI0)" by Ranjeetha Pakiam, Feb 24, 2016)

Answer (score 1):

If something ends in -centric, it shows focus on the subject word. So in this case, 'U.S.-centric' means the same as 'U.S.-focused' or something mainly concerning the U.S..

I am not sure of the context of 'prints' in this sentence, but it could mean the printing of something, or newspapers.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of *[prints](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/print#print__22)* here is a relatively uncommon one. Oxford Dictionaries Online does provide a definition:

> 1.2 (usually **the prints**) *informal* A newspaper:
>
> > the report’s contents were widely summarized in the public prints

I can only find it online in older publications, for instance

> This very circumstance of itself, when related by the reporters, and published in the prints, must cause a sensation through this empire

in *[Antiquated Scrupulosity Contrasted with Modern Liberality](https://books.google.com/books?id=dh-8dUxYDyUC&pg=PA41)* by an Abraham Bagnell, 1829.

But Barnabas Gan, the quoted forecaster, resides in Singapore, and perhaps this usage is more familiar there. *US-centric [print] remains hopeful* or *[the] US-centric [press|media] remains hopeful* would mean more or less the same thing in this context.

As noted in another answer, the suffix *[-centric](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-centric)* refers to being oriented to a particular center. Thus, a *US-centric newspaper* would be one which reports primarily on the United States, or primarily about how events affect the United States. It can be disapproving in some cases, e.g. a *Eurocentric worldview* is one that places Europe at the center of the world, with the implicit derogation of views from other parts of the world. Whether Gan intended *US-centric* to be disapproving of such a publication cannot really be known from this article alone, however.